# Exporting Oracle SQL database

Tags: oracle, oracle-export-dump

I am exporting a database on Oracle from Linux to Windows.

I have already tried all of the answers on Stack Overflow.

When using exp, I receive this:

```
Message 206 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=EXP

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracl

Invalid format of Export utility name

Verify that ORACLE_HOME is properly set

Export terminated unsuccessfully

EXP-00000: Message 0 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=EXP
```

I have exported the ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID, and PATH:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=xe
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
```

I have also tried using expdp and this gives me this error:

```
UDE-00013: Message 13 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=UDE
UDE-00019: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

I am really stuck for answers now.

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT: 
[Oracle_env.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKz6D.png)

Comment: Your home path is wrong, it's missing the initial `/` - try with `export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe`. (Also, shouldn't the path be `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` ? You can [use `oraenv.sh`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL124) to set everything up properly)

Comment: Have done both of these but still no luck

Comment: I meant to source the provided oraenv.sh, not create your own - did you follow the link? If you've moved those commands to your own file, are you executing it or sourcing it (`. oraenv.sh`)? Either way, what does `echo $ORACLE_HOME` show right before you run exp/expdp; and what does `ls -ld $ORACLE_HOME` report?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Was a stupid syntax error!

Comment: Add your comment as an answer and will mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ORACLE_HOME` path is wrong, it's missing the initial `/`. That means he Oracle tools can't see the files they need, hence the errors you're seeing. Your modification of the `PATH` should also be adding the `bin` directory within that home:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=xe
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

If you put those commands into a file then you have to source the file so make the changes apply to your current session. You can also set them directly in your shell profile script (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`), by copying those three lines into that file - they will then be set automatically for future log ins.

[Oracle provide a file to set up the environmet](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL124), so instead of setting these yourself you could do:

```
. /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/oracle_env.sh
```

either manually each time you log in, or more usefully by adding that line to your shell profile script.